# Python Gmail API : How to batch download of email attachments and emails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api

I have the below code, which downloads a Gmail email and its attachments. It returns its attachments.

```html
    def gmailAPIDownloadAttachments(self, messageID, userID="me"):
        try:
            service = self.gmailAPIService
            self.GLogger.info("Attempting to download attachments from messageID (" +str(messageID)+ ")")
            message = self.gmailAPIGetFullMessage(messageID, userID=userID)
            if message is False:
                self.GLogger.error("Failed to extract message (" +str(messageID)+ ") for downloading attachments")
                return False
            attachmentList = list()
            payload = message['payload']
            if 'parts' in payload:
                parts = payload['parts']
                for part in parts:
                    if part['filename']:
                        if 'data' in part['body']:
                            data = part['body']['data']
                        else:
                            att_id = part['body']['attachmentId']
                            att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=userID, messageId=messageID, id=att_id).execute()
                            data = att['data']
                        file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
                        filename = part['filename']
                        extSearch = filename.find('.')
                        if extSearch == -1:
                            ext = ""
                            partFileName = filename[0:extSearch]
                        else:
                            ext = filename[extSearch+1:]
                            partFileName = filename[0:extSearch]

                        theAttachment = Attachment(filename,partFileName, ext, file_data)
                        attachmentList.append(theAttachment)

            self.GLogger.info("Successfully downloaded attachments from messageID (" +str(messageID)+ ")")
            return(attachmentList)
        except:
            self.GLogger.error("Encountered an error while attempting to download email attacments from messageID (" +str(messageID)+ ")")
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self.GLogger.exception(tb)
            return False
```

I understand how to convert fetching messages into batching. For example, this is how one could batch-fetch messages:

```html
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
import json

batch = BatchHttpRequest()

#assume we got messages from Gmail query API
for message in messages:
    batch.add(service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'],
                                             format='raw'))
batch.execute()
for request_id in batch._order:
    resp, content = batch._responses[request_id]
    message = json.loads(content)
    #handle your message here, like a regular email object
```

However, the attachments aspect seem to have logic and other possible fetches such as in this part:

```html
att_id = part['body']['attachmentId']
att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=userID, messageId=messageID, id=att_id).execute()
data = att['data']
```

How can I effectively batch both fetching the message and its attachments? I would like to be able to quickly fetch many emails at once.

Comment: You first need to get the message via `messages.get` and, using that response, call `attachments.get`. Therefore, I don't think there's a way to fetch both a message and its attachments with the same batch request, since one request is dependent on the response from the other one. Of course you could get all the attachments from all the messages in a batch request, but this cannot be the same batch request by which you retrieved the messages. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi, was my comment useful to you? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer.